# Is there some way to access the audio element loaded on `THREE.Audio` to attach media event listeners?

Tags: three.js

I am using THREE.Audio to create an audio visualizer and want to know if (once the audio file is loaded) is there a way to attach media event listener `canplaythrough` to the element so the entire media can be played without interruption.

```
loadAudio() {
  // Create AudioListener and add it to the camera
  this.listener = new THREE.AudioListener();
  this.camera.add(this.listener);

  // Create global audio source
  this.sound = new THREE.Audio(this.listener);

  // Load a sound and set it as the audio object's buffer
  this.audioLoader = new THREE.AudioLoader();
  this.audioLoader.load('../../audio/maceo-plex.mp3', (buffer) => {
    this.sound.setBuffer(buffer);
    this.animate();
    console.log('audio is loaded');
  });

  // Create an AudioAnalyser, passing in the sound and desired fftSize
  this.fftSize = 128;
  this.analyser = new THREE.AudioAnalyser(this.sound, this.fftSize);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When loading an audio via `THREE.AudioLoader`, you effectively load an audio buffer which is part of the Web Audio API. The buffer itself as well as the respective `AudioBufferSourceNode` do not have a `canplaythrough` event.

For your use case, it's better to create your audio object as follows:

```
const audio = new THREE.Audio( listener );

const mediaElement = new Audio( 'path/to/my/audio.ogg' );
mediaElement.loop = true;
mediaElement.play();

audio.setMediaElementSource( mediaElement );
```

In this way, you can attach event listeners to `mediaElement`. Besides, it's not necessary to download the entire file all of once which actually happens when using `AudioLoader`. I suggest you study the following official example which contains all basic elements of an audio visualizer:

https://threejs.org/examples/webaudio_visualizer

`three R105`

Comment: So there's no need for me to load a buffer of the audio? This approach is better if I want to access event listeners by creating an html audio element. Thank you!